# Can SIPP be pinned to a cpu in linux?

Tags: linux, sipp

I have to do some testing and I am tasked with using SIPP on a linux machine to run these tests. In addition to that I was asked to find out if SIPP can be pinned to be only used by 1 CPU for each UAC instance of it. Thus far I have tried to use taskset to do this but I could not get that to work. Can anyone please help and point me in the correct direction to an answer.

Here is an example of how I tried to pin the instance of SIPP to a CPU:

```
[felipe@localhost sipp-3.3.990]$ taskset -p 0x0 9491
```

pid 9491's current affinity mask: 1
taskset: failed to set pid 9491's affinity: Operation not permitted

Comment: you can run sipp from docker container with 1 CPU..